# DIY BLDC ESC problem is causing MOSFETS and motor to get very hot very fast, HELP

Tags: power-electronics

Hey everyone this is my first time reaching out to the community for help to see if someone can show me what I'm not seeing on this. Basically I am trying to make my own ESC for a BLDC and before anyone says the commercial solution is cheaper and easier, I know. I'm doing it to try learn some more in-depth programming/power electronic as well as to make a customisable version that's all my own work for if i want to use it for something else down the road, so lets get into the issue.

The problem is although I'm using a 20kHz PwM signal at a variable duty on the high side HBridge generated by direct timer control on the atmega328p (Arduino NANO), to try "chop"/control the current (also to control speed when using Zero-Cross detection) as well as keeping the lowside HBridge fully grounded on any given step, the MOSFETs (N-channel irf1405s 55V and 160A rated) are getting really really hot very fast and so is the motor like over 150 degrees Celsius hot even after only running for 30 - 120 seconds. The actual motor spins just fine however, I can even change the speed using an Arduino delay timed step change (although I do have the hardware and did have the software for BEMF step changing too I disabled it to try simplify things while attempting to solve the heating issue as its my main priority).

I've attached my code and schematic if anyone can see something on this that I can't it would be much appreciated because I'm outta ideas I've tried adding lots of different changes to the hard and software with no luck.

I built a version using P Chanels on the high side and a BJT to switch them whilst PWMing the low side, it had a similar heating problem although abit slower. I built a version using a BJT to feed the PWM coming from the Arduino OUTPUT to both HIN and LIN on the ir2101, since LIN is inverted I was hoping to connect the bridge to ground whenever it wasn't being pulsed in an attempt to give the collapsing magnetic field of the BLDC coil somewhere to flow but even though the scope showed the output was pulsing correctly when I connected the motor this didn't work either, at the end of it all I went back to the attached schematic and code but I still can't seem to stop the MOSFETs and motor from getting really hot because of what I assume is excessive current draw (possibly from an EMF building up in the coils and trying to ground through the FETS body when the HBridge goes to floating??).

If I increase the duty to 60-70%+ the MOSFETs also just straight up explode even with some long dead time coded in using delay functions. I'm using a 12V 6.5Ah lead acid battery for testing as its close to the power supply I would use the ESC with normally and an amount of power something like this should handle no problems when working properly.

So to conclude if anyone with experience in power electronics or who has any ideas on how to fix my heating issue is reading this please help. Any equations I may need to consider more carefully, or advanced things a fairly beginner engineer like me might have missed would be much appreciated since at this point I've killed more Fets than I'd like to have.

[image: Schematic]

```
My Code: 

int StepCounter = 1; //step counter
int RawDutyCycle = 0; //raw pot input storage variable
int Duty = 0; //duty cycle

//setup lowside pins for standalone direct port manipulation
int LowSideA = PD2; //pin D2
int LowSideB = PD5; //pin D5
int LowSideC = PD7; //pin D7

//setup highside pins to be PWM outputs at port level
int HighSideA = PD3; //OC2B D3
int HighSideB = PB1; //OC1A D9
int HighSideC = PB2; //OC1B D10

//defins all the PWM pin States neatly
#define HighSideASetON (1<<COM2A0) + (1<<COM2B1) + (1<<WGM20)
#define HighSideASetOFF (0<<COM2A0) + (0<<COM2B1) + (1<<WGM20)

#define HighSideBSetON (1<<COM1A1) + (0<<COM1B1)
#define HighSideCSetON (0<<COM1A1) + (1<<COM1B1)
#define HighSideBandCSetOFF (0<<COM1A1) + (0<<COM1B1)

void setup() {
  
  //Sets data direction of all pins
  DDRD = (1<<LowSideA) | (1<<LowSideB) | (1<<LowSideC) | (1<<HighSideA);
  DDRB = (1<<HighSideB) | (1<<HighSideC); 
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);

  //timer1 PWM pins D9 and D10 setup
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;
  TCCR1A = (1<<COM1A1) + (1<<COM1B1) + (1<<WGM11); //phase correct pwm
  TCCR1B = (1<<WGM13) + (1<<CS11);
  ICR1 = 100; //set kHz
  OCR1A = 10; //set duty
  OCR1B = 10; //set duty

  //timer2 PWM pin D3 setup
  TCCR2A = 0;
  TCCR2B = 0;
  TCCR2A = (1<<COM2A0) + (1<<COM2B1) + (1<<WGM20); //phase correct pwm
  TCCR2B = (1<<CS21) + (1<<WGM22);
  OCR2A = 100; //set kHz
  OCR2B = 10; //set duty

  //Sets all 3 H-bridges to float
  TCCR1A = (0<<COM1A1) + (0<<COM1B1);
  TCCR2A = (0<<COM2A1) + (0<<COM2B1);
  PORTD = (1<<LowSideA) + (1<<LowSideB) + (1<<LowSideC);
  
}

void loop() {
  
  RawDutyCycle = analogRead(A0); //read the pot
  int WaitTime = map(RawDutyCycle, 0, 1023, 10000, 500);
  Duty = 50;
  OCR1A = Duty; //set duty
  OCR1B = Duty;
  OCR2B = Duty;
  
  delayMicroseconds(WaitTime);
  
  switch(StepCounter){

    case 1: //step1
    TCCR1A = HighSideBandCSetOFF;
    PORTD = (1<<LowSideA) + (0<<LowSideB) + (1<<LowSideC);
    TCCR2A = HighSideASetON;
    StepCounter = 2;
    break;

    case 2: //step2
    TCCR1A = HighSideBandCSetOFF;
    PORTD = (1<<LowSideA) + (1<<LowSideB) + (0<<LowSideC);
    TCCR2A = HighSideASetON;
    StepCounter = 3;
    break;

    case 3: //step3
    TCCR2A = HighSideASetOFF;
    PORTD = (1<<LowSideA) + (1<<LowSideB) + (0<<LowSideC);
    TCCR1A = HighSideBSetON;
    StepCounter = 4;
    break;

    case 4: //step4
    TCCR1A = HighSideBandCSetOFF;
    PORTD = (0<<LowSideA) + (1<<LowSideB) + (1<<LowSideC);
    TCCR1A = HighSideBSetON;
    StepCounter = 5;
    break;

    case 5: //step5
    TCCR1A = HighSideBandCSetOFF;
    PORTD = (0<<LowSideA) + (1<<LowSideB) + (1<<LowSideC);
    TCCR1A = HighSideCSetON;
    StepCounter = 6;
    break;

    case 6: //step6
    TCCR1A = HighSideBandCSetOFF;
    PORTD = (1<<LowSideA) + (0<<LowSideB) + (1<<LowSideC);
    TCCR1A = HighSideCSetON;
    StepCounter = 1;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: prob better on EE SE, but a hot motor generally means too much current due to too low a voltage.

Comment: Show scope waveforms. Add current sense resistors in the phase and get a differential voltage measurement to represent current if you must.

Comment: "*as well as keeping the lowside HBridge fully grounded on any given step*" Clarify what you mean here. One test is to wire two of three phases as an H-bridge to a brushed motor and modify your code accordingly. See if that runs as expected at full throttle and with PWM speed adjustment. Is this on a PCB or breadboard?

Comment: The highsides are being activated by using the TCCR1A and TCCR2A registers since they are running PWM

Comment: The motor also had no load and is small 900kv ebay motor. I have already tested the circuit with a brushed dc motor and every works as it should its just when I connected the bldc i get problems i think due to its rather high impedance

Comment: So using one phase, it works with a brushed dc motor.  But 3 phases with PWM, it does not work and everything gets hot.

Comment: Yeah so if I modify the code and connect a brushed dc motor to both phases say + of the motor to phase A and - of the motor to phase B and rewrite the code accordingly i can operate the board as a full bridge controlling both direction as well as speed using pwm on the highside with no issues, the fets stay cool and all is well but as soon as I connect the bldc and use the above code everything gets super hot and eventually the fets fail.

Comment: You need to get a scope trace of output as DKNguyen says.  You should also add your comments to your question including driving the DC motor so that others don't have to sift througn comments to try to help.  Delete your comments after you add.

Comment: What happens if you remove D3, D4 and D7?  Similarily low side.

Comment: If i remove the discharge diodes from all gates things get the same level of hot with no real difference

Comment: what happens if you run it without a motor?

Comment: With the bldc removed everything works fine no heating of the mosfets so I would assume that rules shoot through current out as the problem

Comment: So what happens if you eliminate PWM.  Drive high like you drive low.

Comment: the MOSFETs get super hot and considering only 60 ish duty cycle killed the fets It does too